# Linear independence of the functions $1,\cos(x),\cos(2x)$

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

I want to show that the functions $1,\cos(x),\cos(2x)$ are linearly independent in $C[-\pi,\pi]$. I computed the Wronskian determinat of these functions but at the points $x=0,-\pi,\pi$ the obtained determinant vanishes. So, I couldn't obtained the required result. Can you me help me in showing that these are linearly dependent or linearly independent in $C[-\pi,\pi]$.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How about trying a point that isn't $0,-\pi$, or $\pi$?

Comment: at points in $(0,\pi)$ and in $(-\pi,0)$, the Wronskian of the functions is different from zero. So, I consider that these are linearly independent in $(0,\pi)$ and in $(-\pi,0)$ but in the book the author claims that these are linearly independent in $[-\pi,\pi]$.

Comment: Take care to differentiate between the zero function, and functions that are zero at some points but nonzero at other points.

Comment: Some similar older questions: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/238833/proof-that-1-sin-x-cos-x-sin-2x-cos-2x-is-linearly-independent and http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/604112/functions-cos2x-sin2ax-1-independent-and-dependent

Answer (score 4):

Suppose $a+b\cos x + c\cos 2x = 0$ for all $x \in [-\pi,\pi]$, where $a,b,c$ are real constants.

$x = 0$ yields $a+b+c = 0$,

$x = \pi/2$ yields $a-c = 0$,

$x = \pi$ yields $a-b+c = 0$

Are there any solutions besides $a = b = c = 0$?

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Linear dependency in $C[-\pi,\pi]$ would require a non-trivial triple $(c_1,c_2,c_3)$ of constants such that the equation
$$
c_1\cdot1+c_2\cdot\cos x+c_3\cdot\cos2x=0\qquad(*)
$$
holds for all $x\in[-\pi,\pi]$. If that is the case, then the equation $(*)$ holds for all $x\in(0,\pi)$, too. Your Wronskian calculation on the other hand ...

Answer (score 1):

you should prove that this functions are orthogonal so you can use dot multiply of functions and prove that is 0.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that $a+b\cos x+c\cos 2x=0$ in our interval. Differentiate and set $x=\pi/2$. We get $b=0$.

So $a+c\cos 2x=0$. Set $x=\pi/4$. We get $a=0$.

Answer (score 1):

Try a different value of $x$ in your Wronskian.  **Hint**.  The second row (or column, depending how you set it out) of the Wronskian is
$$0\ ,\quad -\sin x\ ,\quad -2\sin2x\ :$$
taking $x$ to be a multiple of $\pi$ will make this $(0,0,0)$ which is of no use to you.  So try something other than a multiple of $\pi$.